# Need to understand memory management when using "unsigned char" to point to raw data buffer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, unsigned-char

My question is in the code below. I'd like to understand if there's such a thing as "retaining" when it comes to "unsigned char" pointers. Please explain.

```
// MyObject.h

@interface myObject : NSObject {

    unsigned char   *myData;
}

// MyObject.m

-(void)makeNewData
{

    if (myData) { free(myData); }
    myData = [self createBitmapContextData:myCGImageRef];

    //Here is my question: do I need a "retain" call equivalent on the next line?
    //[myData retain];

}

- (unsigned char*)createBitmapContextData:(CGImageRef)fromImage
{

    CGContextRef cgctx = [self createARGBBitmapContextFromImage:myCGImage];
    if (cgctx == NULL) { return nil; }

    size_t w = CGImageGetWidth(myCGImage);
    size_t h = CGImageGetHeight(myCGImage);
    CGRect rect = {{0,0},{w,h}}; 

    CGContextDrawImage(cgctx, rect, myCGImage); 

    unsigned char* data = CGBitmapContextGetData (cgctx);

    CGContextRelease(cgctx);

    return data;

}
```

Comment: NSData is an object wrapper for a raw buffer. Will that do?

Comment: @mackross Possibly, I'll just need more help. Let's say I do this: `NSData *myNSData = [[NSData alloc]initWithBytes:data length:sizeof(data)];` How would I access `data[index]` with NSData?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such thing as “retaining” a raw pointer.

As mackross says, `NSData` can be used to hold on to data when you allocate it yourself. However, in this case, you don’t own the data, you‘re merely “getting” it from the `CGContext`, which owns it. Your reference becomes invalid when the `CGContext` is released. In this case, you need to own a reference to the context until you no longer need the pointer.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly the part I needed to understand.